# How do you save new index location in persistentcontainer?

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data

I have a tableview where I have added the ability to move the location of rows. I am able to use the "swapAt" function to update my array and it works fine. The problem is that when I close and re-open the app, the rows continue to show in their old IndexPath. How can I also update the index location in the PersistentContainer so that when I open the app, it is updated with the new IndexPath?

I tried calling the save method of the context but it does not work.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,      UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    var toDoList = [Item] ()
    var count: Int {
        toDoList.count
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addItem))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .edit, target: self, action: #selector(editItem))
        
        title = "Todo"
        
        loadItem()
        
    }

    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection   section: Int) -> Int {
        return toDoList.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = toDoList [indexPath.row].title
        
        if toDoList[indexPath.row].checkmark == true {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark }
        else {
                cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
        return cell
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if toDoList[indexPath.row].checkmark == false {
            toDoList[indexPath.row].checkmark = true } else {
                toDoList[indexPath.row].checkmark = false
        }
        
        tableView.reloadData()
        saveItem()
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
       
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        toDoList.swapAt(sourceIndexPath.row, destinationIndexPath.row)
        
        saveItem()
        
    }
    
    @objc func addItem () {
        
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Add new category", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        var textField = UITextField()
        
        let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (action) in
            
            let newItem = Item(context: self.context)
            newItem.title = textField.text
            newItem.checkmark = false
            newItem.order = Int64(self.count)
            
            self.toDoList.append(newItem)
            
            self.saveItem()
        }
        
        ac.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
            alertTextField.placeholder = "Create new item"
            textField = alertTextField
        }
        
        ac.addAction(submitAction)
        present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
    func saveItem () {

        do {
           try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("This is the \(error)")
        }
        
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func loadItem () {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
        let sortRequest = NSSortDescriptor(key: "order", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sortRequest]
        do {
           toDoList = try context.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("the error is \(error)")
        }
        
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    
    @objc func editItem () {
        
        if tableView.isEditing {
            tableView.isEditing = false
        } else {
            tableView.isEditing = true
        }}
    
   
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
          if editingStyle == .delete {
            context.delete(toDoList[indexPath.row])
            saveItem()
            self.toDoList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
           

        }
      

    }
        
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are doing the sorting of `toDoList` when you read  it from the store.

Comment: added the full code

Comment: Where do you declare the swapAt function

Comment: I got it to work based on your comment below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tackle this problem by having an index property in the Coredata entity; this index reflects the position of the element in the table view. In the `swapAtFunction` add the logic to switch the index properties of the two elements.

Then, when you fetch the entities, you add a predicate to your request, to sort the elements by the index property.

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<EntityName>(entityName: "EntityName")
    let sortDescripor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "index", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescripor]
```

Then execute `fetchRequest` as you normally would, and assign the resulting array to the `UICollectionView`'s `Datasource`.